# Limpiar un EditText que tiene almacenada una String

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy creando una app en Android Studio, y quiero que en cierto momento lo que se escribió en el EditText se borre o la caja se limpie, ya intente de todo y no puedo solucionarlo. Este es mi codigo:

```
public void check1(View view){

        String RESP = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
        if (RESP.equals("4"))
        {

            if(MostrarCorrecto.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                MostrarCorrecto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MostrarIncorrecto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
**Es en este punto donde quiero que se limpie el EditText**
            }
```

Comment: ¿Probaste a poner esto: **`RESP.setText("");`** en el punto donde quieres que se limpie el elemento?

Comment: Explica con más detalles que lo que intentas hacer. ¿Quieres que cuando escribas "4" en el EditText se borre el texto automáticamente o mediante alguna acción? ¿Puedes agregar mas detalles?, para limpiar un EditText simplemente obten su referencia y haz `.setText("")`.

Comment: Hola .Adrian.., te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, agrega lo que preguntan los compañeros, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo deberias poner setText donde lo quieres con doble comilla dentro en:

> **Es en este punto donde quiero que se limpie el EditText**

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tu clase debe implementar `OnClickListener` y tienes que agregar un listener al `EditText` en el `onCreate`.

Luego, en el `onClick` haces el cambio.

Algo así:

```
/*
  *OJO,si ya tienes implements OnClickListener 
  *NO CAMBIES NADA EN ESTA 1ª LÍNEA
  *si no lo tienes, AGREGA SÓLO esto implements OnClickListener 
*/
public class TuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*código del layout y demás*/
        //...
        /*
           *Aquí suponemos que tu edittext tiene el id editText
           *en el layout, después de R.id. debes poner el id que éste tenga
        */
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); 
        /*Agregas el listener*/
        editText.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*
           *Atención a la convención de nombres, las variables en mayúsculas
           *representan constantes en la convención de nombres de Java
           *No es motivo de error, pero dificulta la legilibilidad del código
        */
        String strResp = editText.getText().toString();
        if (strResp.equals("4"))
        {

            if(MostrarCorrecto.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                MostrarCorrecto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MostrarIncorrecto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            /*Es en este punto donde quiero que se limpie el EditText*/
            /*Aquí sólo funcionará cuando escribas un 4*/
            editText.setText("");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Realmente debería implementar `onClick` en el `EditText`?, su pregunta suena mas a verificar campos. Si lo hace así, solo entraría al `EditText` al hacer click y no cuando cambie el Focus u otra acción distinta al mismo. Yo creo que bastaría con decirle que debería obtener la referencia del EditText y hacer `.setText("");` en la misma.

Comment: @Andrespengineer para llevar a cabo la verificación necesita desencadenar algún evento, sea cual sea. Si no es al escribir algo en el `EditText` mismo, puede ser al pulsar en un botón o en otra parte. De acuerdo a su código parecería que quisiera verificar lo que se escribe en el `EditText`

Comment: En caso de que requiera la accion del click encajaría perfecto. Pero desde mi punto de vista, a la pregunta le falta información que el debería especificar mediante una edición.

Comment: Tienes razón en eso @Andrespengineer.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo deberia quedar asi

```
public void check1(View view){

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); //Refecias tu EditText en una variable
    String RESP = editText.getText().toString(); //Obtienes el texto
    if (RESP.equals("4"))
    {

        if(MostrarCorrecto.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        {
            MostrarCorrecto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MostrarIncorrecto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        editText.setText(""); //Limpia el EditText
    }
}
```